# grepping foo and bar

Tags: grep, search

I am looking for a command options for `grep` to 
find files with the occurences of `foo` and `bar`.

Grepping with

```
grep -r -e foo -e bar .
```

shows files which have only `foo` or only `bar` and files which have `foo` and `bar`.

Is it possible with `grep` to find only files which have both `foo` and `bar` (and display the lines that match either `foo` or `bar` or both in those files *only*)?

Example:

```
echo foo > file1
echo bar > file2
(echo foo;echo;echo bar) >file3
echo barfoo > file4
```

the grep cmd:

```
grepcmd -r -e foo -e bar .
./file3:foo
./file3:bar
./file4:barfoo
```

Answer (score 10):

#### to find *files* that contain both:

(assuming GNU `grep`/`xargs`)

```
grep -rl --null abc . | xargs -r0 grep -l bcd
```

And if you want to see the lines that contain `abc` or `bcd` or both in the files that contain both `abc` and `bcd`:

```
grep -rl --null abc . |
  xargs -r0 grep -l --null bcd |
  xargs -r0 grep -He abc -e bcd
```

#### to match *lines* that contain both:

```
grep -re 'foo.*bar' -e 'bar.*foo' .
```

That works as long as the patterns don't overlap.

```
grep -re 'abc.*bcd' -e 'bcd.*abc' .
```

Would fail to find the lines that contain `abcd`.

If your `grep` has `-P` for PCRE:

```
grep -rP '^(?=.*abc).*bcd' .
```

would work.

Or, POSIXly:

```
find . ! -type d -exec awk '/abc/ && /bcd/ {print FILENAME ":" $0}' {} +
```

You could also use `agrep`:

```
agrep -r 'abc;bcd' .
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! The keywords mustn't be in one line, does grep parse multiple lines?

Comment: None of the commands shows two lines. I modified my question again. So if I search for `foo` and `bar`, I want to have listed the files and the lines with `foo` and `bar` like I'd search for only one string.

Comment: @bersch, sorry, I don't understand what you mean, please give an example with expected output.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas +1 for `agrep`, anyways where you find this tool ?

Comment: @RahulPatil, it used to come with ht://dig, but you can find it as a separate package now on some distributions. The `a` is for approximate which is its main _feature_ (one you'd expect from a search engine like htdig).

Comment: updated the question, should be now more clear.

Comment: @bersch, so how is `grep -rl --null abc . |
  xargs -r0 grep -l --null bcd |
  xargs -r0 grep -He abc -e bcd` not answering the question? (replace abc, bcd with foo, bar)?

Comment: @RahulPatil, sorry, not `ht://dig`, that was [glimpse](http://webglimpse.net/). Bad memory.